# Get values (a array) out a mysql database by opening a php file on a other host

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

This is wat needs to happen:

I need to get user information out a MySql database.

**But i don't want to insert the password of my database in the php file.** Because that file won't be hosted on my own server. Nobody must see that password when they access the server by ftp and edit the php file.

My first solution that didn't work was opening a php file from my own host and reading the output (i made a script that connects to the database and outputs a long string) and converted the output to an array by splitting the values.
This did not work because of security reasons in php.

I can't create a extra account for my database that has read-only access because my host won't allow me. (hostinger.co.uk)

I also thought about using a iFrame and load the file on my host. And read it using javascript to read it. But again, security won't allow me to edit it.

Does someone know a way to fix this?

Comment: API api api api api *echos*

Comment: You could create code on your site that retrieves the data and then sends it to your buddies server. If you did that, you'd have to make an efficient API to communicate between the two. I am assuming that this is what Darren meant as well, though if you meant something else Darren, correct me brozki :)

Comment: I'm actually working with pheanstalk currently, a queue system that uses TCP to communicate to servers via a port. This could be useful for your situation if you decide to take the API route.

Comment: wait... that doesn't make sense though, your host wont let you create another username? When you go into phpMyAdmin, you should be able to create another username. I don't see a reason for you to only be limited to one even if your account is "shared hosting"

Comment: @Webeng i contacted the support service of my host, and they told me i can't. When i create a database, i can only create 1 user. Even inside phpMyAdmin i can't create a user. It's super weird.

Comment: Is it difficult to write my own API? I searched it on google. But hard to find a simple instruction. Does someone have a simple instruction how to make a api that can sort of do what i want?

Comment: hmmm that is super weird... you know what... (not to be annoying or anything) but I'm gonna go to my phpmyadmin of my shared hosting account 1 sec to see something. I believe you that the guy said you can't, but I have had my fair share of tec suppor that don't know that much :). If I find anything there, I'll let you know

Comment: If your shared hosting wont even let you create another account for your phpmyadmin, there is a good chance they definitely won't give you root access to your server which you probably will need to set up an API

Comment: @Webeng haha thats no problem dude :) thanks for helping. O and i don't think i have root access, but i can create CRON jobs? maybe is that something

Comment: I just checked my shared hosting account and your right... you are not able to create a user... I have a dedicated server that has the "Users" tab right before "Exports" and the shared hosting doesn't have it... shame...

Comment: Oh and cron jobs. I mean you can use them for running scripts every, though you'd have to make the code a bit "hacky" if you know what I mean lol, though it is doable... but not at all clean

Comment: @Webeng i asked btw the support guys for a solution (because i could not create 2 account for 1 database, i thought maybe i can mirror a full-access database with a read-only database) but then they say that i can create a php file with a code that just sync all the data from the full-access database to the read-only database. And that sounds stupid, because tho whole idea is that i can't write to the read-only database -.-

Comment: Could you possibly just copy your database and send your buddy a copy? And update his database every time yours has been updated. He would have all your information on his server, and I dont know if that bothers you, but he wouldn't be able to modify your data on your server

Comment: @Webeng That sucks for me haha, haha yeah i understand

Comment: I understand the concern of him controlling your server. Is it also bad for him to have that information permanently? It could be, I just don't know what the specific situation is, if it is sensitive data or not

Comment: @Webeng yeah.. i could do that (a nice backup plan, thanks ;) ), but the information can change daily. And i like the idea that everything would be in sync automaticly ;)

Comment: Well you can actually do something pretty "sync" if that is an option. I'll add an example in my answer cause it needs to be more elaborated than a comment. It might be useful, who knows

Comment: @Webeng well i just make website's for friends. And they need personal information on the bottom of the website. I like the idea that their name, street, mobile number etc. came from my database. I store their information in my database for administration and they can edit it on my own website. (this also mean they can maybe edit their pages in the feauture by going to my site, edit some text and upload it back into the database. On their website is it now also updated) much text, but i like the idea haha

Comment: @Webeng if i need to sync then i have to, and would be nice if it works :) but that also means that my friends have the website data of my other friends. Is there no other way to just place a script on host A and read a file from host B?

Comment: Read a file sure `fopen('http://yoursite.com/file.txt', "r")` though it would be visible to the whole world, not just your friend.

Comment: If you wanted to make that method somewhat secure, you would do something like `fopen('http://yoursite.com/dfio$@#dsflkjsdfli.txt', "r");`. Your hosting site probably already blocks directory listing which means people wouldn't be able to see what is inside each directory of your site, they would only be able to see the file if they know the name

Comment: @Webeng i will test it right now :) i already tried it with a other script. That gave me a security error. O and btw, the information i'm asking is already visible on the webpage. In my case, i think it won't be a problem :)

Comment: Ohh ok, so you don't even need to use the database? I mean in that case, you have a lottt of options lol. Not just a text file, a CSV file might be more practical, but if you want a text then sure, why complicate things

Comment: @Webeng i was thinking, if i can read a file, then i will read a php file. My host does the php part (loading stuff out of the database and prints it in plane text) then i read that stuff and splitting it and create a array :) i'm almost done with testing :)

Comment: You won't be able to though xP, php code is server side code, but try it out and let me know. If you do manage, my world will shift upside down and I will have learned something new :)

Comment: @ProMike360 MySQLi isn't bad at all, it's just a light version though less powerful that MySQL. I have never used it before so I don't know the ins and outs. Oh and I wrote the option3 btw with how to read a text file

Comment: @ProMike360 oh and if my answer worked for your situation, please accept it (green check mark) so that future users know it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OPTION 1:**

Since you want to make sure your buddies server doesn't have access to the MySQL server info (username, password, etc), your safest bet is to connect to the database from your server, and just communicate between the two servers what needs to be retrieved.

As Darren mentioned in the comments, an API would do this just fine. Since there are a lot of open source libraries out there that can get the job done, I will recommend you one: **pheanstalk**

pheanstalk is a php client that works on top of the beanstalk library, which is basically a queue.

You could set up a queue on each server, and configure the communication to happen between the 2 servers. Then you would have **worker.php** scripts running every second (or 10 seconds or however so often you like) looking for commands being sent from 1 server, taking those commands in, processing them, and sending back the information to the main computer.

**OPTION 2:**

Instead of accessing your database, you can create a copy of yours, and have his server contain a copy.

**Key points of option 2:**

If his server isn't capable of carrying a full fledged MySQL database, there is MySQLi, which is very similar, but the only difference is that it is basically a file that you keep in your server. That is the benefit since it is **LIGHT** (hence the "i" from MySQLi). The downside is that the database isn't as "powerful", some operations might be limited, though that is to be expected, but good none the less.

If your friend has a database however, then better yet since it will have all the capabilities.

Now since I am assuming you would need to keep their copy of your database up-to-date, you can create a function that would send a request to your buddies server on what was updated. This is an API since it is intercommunication between processes behind the scenes, but probably wouldn't need any root access as some other API's might require.

Though the hastle here is that you would literally have to call that function every time you do any updates... :(

---

**Edited:**

**OPTION 3**

After talking a bit with the OP in the comments, another possibility came up. In his particular case, he might be willing to have a file in a public directory available for his buddies user to read. For example, lets say his file was located in:

```
http://www.example.com/hiddenfiles/dfjios4wr238#@.txt
```

To access what is inside that file, you would have to know the name (and the name was specifically designed to work as a password, hence even though the information isn't sensative for the OP's specific situation, it's always best practice to stay consistent and think safe xD).

To access the file, the following could be done:

```
$path = 'http://www.example.com/hiddenfiles/dfjios4wr238#@.txt';
$fileHandle = fopen($path, "r");
while ($line = fgets($fileHandle))
{
  echo "--> {$line}";
}
fclose();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction! In my case i think it won't work because i have zero-access to my root :( but maybe is this the perfect solution for someone else :) o btw, i'm already using MySQLi for getting data out of my database.. is that a bad thing? haha

Comment: I have only 1 problem with the third option, if i use your code and use a file that is hosted on the same server everything works perfect. But when i upload the txt file on a other host the page takes minutes to load and won't output anything. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Yes there is. Make a copy of that file in your friends site somewhere, and have it updated every... 1 minute or 10 minutes or whatever with a cron job

Comment: That way, you only modify the file if it needs updating, and your friends site is the one that has to worry about checking the file periodically, not yours.

Comment: @ProMike360 a cron job is easy to make too, good tutorials on youtube

Comment: I'm going to sleep now (need a little bith of rest haha), i'll be back in 4 hours. I'll keep you informed :) Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Hey, i'm back haha. It's so weird. Let me explain. I have 2 hosts/websites, **Host A** and **Host B**. When i'm using the `fopen` code on **Host A** to **Host B** it works, i can read the title of the page. BUT when i go from **Host B** to **Host A** it won't work. **and now the strange thing** when i go from **Host B** to **http://www.example.com/**. Then it does work?? Why doesn't it work if i go to **Host A**?

Comment: @ProMike360 That is most likely a permissions issue. What directory is the file located in? Instead of trying to open the file via `fopen()`, try just entering the page with your browser. Also, in the CPanel, check if the file has the permission 644, and if it doesn't, change it to 644.

Comment: it has the perission 644. But if i run the code on a local server with php. So i create my own **Host B**, now it works. I can read form **Host A**. Now i think that the problem is on the original **Host B** BUT when i'm on the original **Host B** i can't go to my **Host A** but i can go to example.com and google.com and read them. so weird

Comment: @ProMike360 Well I can't be sure what the problem is there xP, a server can have a million different configuration setups and I'm not an expert in that area, but hopefully you find out why eventually. Oh and if my answer helped guide you in the right direction, please give it a green check mark for future readers to know :)